# Reducing resolution of timers as mitigation against Meltdown and Spectre

Tags: linux, javascript, firefox, meltdown, spectre

I have read that Firefox' current [mitigation](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/01/03/mitigations-landing-new-class-timing-attack/) against Meltdown and Spectre (from 57.x) consists of the following:

> - The resolution of performance.now() will be reduced to 20µs.
> - The SharedArrayBuffer feature is being disabled by default.

Is it correct to assume that substantially reducing the amount of information obtainable from timing (such as reducing the resolution to 20µs is this case) is a very effective way for addressing the issue in the case of JavaScript runtimes, but that one would introduce lots of (far too many) unwanted side-effects when applying something like this "hammer" to the Linux kernel (hence the additional need for [KPTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation), etc.)?

Comment: Very effective? [Not at all](https://gruss.cc/files/fantastictimers.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is only applied to browsers is because there is no way to fully eliminate high-resolution timing information from code being natively executed. For example, the [`RDTSC`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtsc) instruction provides precise, sub-nanosecond resolution timing information to any process. While it is possible to disable this instruction by making it executable only by privileged code (by setting the [`CR4.TSD`](https://wiki.osdev.org/CPU_Registers_x86#CR4) bit), much of userland relies on it. However even if you did successfully disable it without breakage, a timer of similar resolution could be jerry-rigged by incrementing a variable in a fast loop. Userspace code will *always* have nanosecond-precision timing information. Such a timer could be implemented easily:

```
#include <pthread.h>

volatile unsigned long counter = 0;

static void *counter_thread(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
        counter++;
}

static void __attribute__((constructor)) init_counter(void)
{
    pthread_id id;
    pthread_create(&id, NULL, counter_thread, NULL);
}

unsigned long get_counter(void)
{
    return counter;
}
```

Loading this sample library starts a new thread that rapidly increments a variable. It exports a function `get_counter()` that returns the current value of that variable at the time it is called. The counter is incremented at a very high and fairly steady rate, providing a high-resolution timer similar to `RDTSC`.

As a result, there is no way to hide precise timing information from machine code executing on the CPU. It is sometimes possible in JavaScript because it is a managed, high-level language which does not have raw access to CPU instructions, and timing must go through dedicated APIs such as [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) which can have its granularity adjusted by modifying the JavaScript engine. Note that this is not always sufficient, as [a number of other techniques exist](https://gruss.cc/files/fantastictimers.pdf) which can be used to implement high-resolution timers in JavaScript. Some of these additional techniques [have been mitigated](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/177033/106285), but not all. Disabling [JIT](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/a-crash-course-in-just-in-time-jit-compilers/) can drastically reduce timing attacks in JavaScript.

Comment: Turns out, you can use a tight loop in JIT'd Javascript to get the timing you need for Spectre.  It's only interpreted Javascript that can't use a timing loop to get around the lack of a high-resolution clock.

Comment: forest & @Mark +1 I do have two follow-up questions. (Please advise if you want me to post separate new questions on this site.) (1) Is `performance.new()` the central API for timing that all other abstractions  in JavaScript rely upon, or is it just one out of many (perhaps one that was convenient for Firefox authors to update)? (2) Can I somehow disable JavaScript JIT compilation for Firefox?

Comment: @Drux, the first would be better asked on a programming site, the second on SuperUser.

Comment: @Drux It is the central API for high-resolution timing, _but_ there are multiple ways to obtain this timing information. Timing attacks in browsers is still an open problem. As for disabling JIT in Firefox, you can do this by setting `javascript.options.baselinejit` to `false`.

Comment: @forest Re-thx, great answer and comment. I may ask (yet another and this time separate) follow-up question on remaining exposures from "leaking" "too-precise" timing information when JIT is off.

Comment: https://gruss.cc/files/fantastictimers.pdf